# Oracle Fuzzy Search with spaces

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I want to do fuzzy search in Oracle but query is not working with spaces.

ex. Let say we have a table po_test_tmp which has many records

If we execute this query it works fine

```
select score(1), ae.po_number
from po_test_tmp ae
where CONTAINS(po_number, 'fuzzy(po, 50,5000, weight)', 1)> 0
order by score(1) desc;
```

But if we try to search term like PO 123 it with not work

```
select score(1), ae.po_number
from po_test_tmp ae
where CONTAINS(po_number, 'fuzzy(PO 123, 50,5000, weight)', 1)> 0
order by score(1) desc;
```

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 10  
29902. 00000 -  "error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine"
*Cause:    The execution of ODCIIndexStart routine caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages produced by the indextype code and
           take appropriate action.
```

How to do fuzzy search if search term has spaces, and search term can have special character and multiple spaces.

Answer (score 2):

First please check the documentation of the [Fuzzy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm#CCREF0307) operator

> Parameter `term`  - Specify the **word** on which to perform the fuzzy expansion.

Note that a *term* typically does not contain blank and you'll have to split your search in searate terms.

Additionally note that `fuzzy` to be activated, the term must have *at least 3 characters*. So your example with `PO` will not work.

What you can do for your setup is to define an extra `fuzzy` search  for each part of your fuzzy string and combine them with the [`near` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm#CCREF0313) such as follows

```
 contains(po_number,'near (( fuzzy(word1,,,weight),fuzzy(word2,,,weight) ), 2, TRUE)',1) > 0
```

`near` enforces here that both matches must be adjacent (`span` = 2) and ordered (`TRUE`).

The handling of special characters depends on the definition of your `whitespace` and `printjoins` in your *preference*.